# CodeMirror editor scrolls when typing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, codemirror

I have an issue with CodeMirror editor on Firefox. When I type something in the bottom line, every first symbol in scrolls top (making current line invisible) and every second symbol it scrolls back.

Issue occurs only in Firefix 34 on OSX 10.10.1, but not in Chrome or Safari.

Noting unusual:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="txt">Hello my dear friend!
Hello my dear friend!
Hello my dear friend!
Hello my dear friend!
Hello my dear friend!
Hello my dear friend!
Hello my dear friend!</textarea>
```

JS:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("txt"), {
    mode: 'xml',
    lineWrapping: true
});
```

CSS:

```
.CodeMirror {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Here is a small [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6oqu5asz/). Just put cursor after the last symbol, press Enter and start typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to upgrade to the current git master branch, specifically [this patch](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/commit/b8accafbbf0cb9536f425e3f01216a268109ccc9), to get rid of this issue (a new release will come out soon).